# How to cluster data points near each other and assign each cluster a new numeric value?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

If I have an array of data like this:

```
 [[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1], 
  [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1], 
  [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]]
```

How do I cluster each grouping of 1s and assign each grouping of 1s a count such that I get an array like this:

```
 [[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2],
  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2], 
  [1, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 2], 
  [0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Basically trying to identify each cluster of data points and assign that cluster of data points a specific value identifying it.

Comment: either [connected component labeling](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.label), or a clustering algo from [`sklearn.cluster`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html)

Answer (score 0):

The [`skimage.measure.label()`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.label) function (as already mentioned by *Aaron*) should give exactly the result you're looking for:

```
import numpy as np
import skimage

# Initialize example array
arr = np.array([
    [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
    [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
])

# Label connected regions
result = skimage.measure.label(arr)

print(result)
# Output:
# [[1 1 0 0 0 2 2]
#  [1 0 0 0 0 2 2]
#  [1 0 3 3 0 0 2]
#  [0 0 3 3 0 0 0]]
```